# JS для всех адресов, начиающихся с

Tags: javascript

Как в JavaScript сделать @include для всех адресов начинающихся с, ну например, `exapmle.com/exam1/`?

Т.е. чтобы скрипт работал на всех адресах типа:
`exapmle.com/exam1/?ask=2&spl=10&r=0ksdf2ho3832`,
 `exapmle.com/exam1/?make=2&spl=10&r=zklsjfg78t`,
`exapmle.com/exam1/?use=2&spl=10&r=fd578c2601`,
`exapmle.com/exam1/?check=2&spl=10&r=02394mqy8932`,
`exapmle.com/exam1/example12`...

P.S. Подразумевается, что это скрипт для браузера, а не встраиваемый в сайт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо в поле `@include` указать адреса:

```
@include     http://example.com/exam1/*
@include     http://example.com/exam2/*
```

тогда все адреса начинающиеся с этого будут "активными для скрипта".

P.S. разобрался с этим, зашел удалить вопрос... видимо, тоже интересуется, раз поставили "лайк", так что ответил сам.